# What does FILES mean in the CMake source_group function?

Tags: cmake

```
SOURCE_GROUP(Test FILES ${Test_files})
```

Checking the documentation, `FILES` should be a regular expression. But what does `FILES` mean here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what docs you're looking at, but the [docs for v2.8.8](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3asource_group) show the signature to be:

> ```
> source_group(name [REGULAR_EXPRESSION regex] [FILES src1 src2 ...])
> ```

So in this case, "FILES" indicates that the list of files specified in `${Test_files}` should be placed in a group (or file tab for MSVC) named "Test".